# Sbt-assembly unresolved dependency, Scala

Tags: scala, plugins, sbt, sbt-assembly

I'm installing Sbt-Assembly, but am now stuck.

```
Sbt Version (from 'sbt about'): 0.13.8
Current project is built against scala 2.11.6
Sbt, sbt plugins, and build definitions are using Scala 2.10.4
```

## project/assembly.sbt

```
   addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.0")
   resolvers += Resolver.url("bintray-sbt-plugins", url("http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

## build.sbt

```
   scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.6"
```

## ~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt

```
   scalaVersion := "2.11.6"
```

I realize sbt-assembly is for scala 2.10. If I change my project to scala 2.10, I have new unavailable dependencies for 2.10 which is not desirable. Is there a way to configure my project to use 2.10 just for the assembly plugin?

```
  ==== bintray-sbt-plugins: tried
  http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.eed3si9n/sbt-assembly/scala_2.11/sbt_0.13/0.14.0/ivys/ivy.xml

  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
  :: com.eed3si9n#sbt-assembly;0.14.0: not found
  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  
  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.

      com.eed3si9n:sbt-assembly:0.14.0 (scalaVersion=2.11, sbtVersion=0.13)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just remove `scalaVersion` from `global.sbt`.

Because [SBT is recursive](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Organizing-Build.html#sbt+is+recursive) it uses this `scalaVersion` from `global.sbt` when building your build files, which fails because SBT 0.13 is built with Scala 2.10, and so are all SBT plugins.

Comment: This is a very annoying, especially since SBT doesn't look to be built against Scala 2.11+ any time soon (n years later). I'm not entirely clear why defining the version of Scala you want to use for artifacts built by the meta-build should define the version sbt needs to run that build. Doubly annoying because this is *not* clear in the documentation.

Comment: It's the other way around: the meta-build needs to use SBT libraries. Scala 2.11 is going to be used in SBT 1.0 (unsurprisingly, it can't be changed in a minor release).

Comment: It was easy enough to see that SBT 1.0 would use Scala 2.11: but the timeline is still undefined, and this is a pain point. I am curious though: I thought the reason I ran into trouble was that my meta-build built a proper-build definition on the `scalaVersion` it had specified, and my proper-build couldn't run because SBT wasn't aligned with that? Once I stopped specifying a version in my meta-build, my proper-build worked (assuming I hard-coded library dependencies in my meta-build). (I've been wrestling for a week on this. :P)

Comment: No, meta-build with wrong `scalaVersion` shouldn't be able to build the build definition at all (at least I think so).

Comment: Huhn. I think what I was seeing was that the build definition was built but died because it had confused attributes when looking up a library dependency. But this is probably the wrong place to discuss it.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem, what helped was adding `addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.3")` to the `project/plugins.sbt` instead of `plugins.sbt` in the root directory of my project.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @wmiel

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error. Changing sbt-assembly version (from 0.14.3 to 0.14.5) worked. My sbt version was 1.0.3 and I used :
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.5")

Answer (score 1):

Just **don't use** sbt-assembly at all! :) Flat-jars cause conflicts during merging which need to be resolved with assemblyMergeStrategy.
Use the **binary distribution** format plugin that sbt offers which enables you to distribute in binary script, dmg, msi and tar.gz.

Check out [sbt-native-packager](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager)